# Cannot resolve symbol 'Assertions' <-- Error message when trying to use AssertJ in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, assertj

Similar to some other Questions, I find IntelliJ mysteriously refuses to recognize AssertJ library. I am asking again as (a) I have tried the various suggestions, and (b) I have a very simple example anyone can try themselves.

In IntelliJ 2018 and IntelliJ 2019 pre-release, I create a new project using the Maven archetype [`maven-archetype-quickstart`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.4) version 1.4.

[AssertJ 3 requires Java 8](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core.html). So I changed these two lines in the POM for `1.7` to `11`.

```xml
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

I add this to the POM:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Using the *Maven* panel in IntelliJ, I executed a `clean` and `install`.

Seems good. I verify the `org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1` library appears in the *Project* panel of IntelliJ. The app runs, with *Hello World* appearing on the console in IntelliJ.

In the `App.java` file, I add this `import` statement.

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.* ;
```

Error reported in the IDE editor:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Assertions'

Some people suggest a corrupted Maven cache. So I quit IntelliJ, and I delete the `.m2` folder in my home folder. I re-open my project in IntelliJ, and re-execute the Maven `clean` & `install`. Many things are downloading, so I know the Maven cache is indeed being recreated.

Yet, still the error in my editor, `Cannot resolve symbol 'Assertions'`.

No Java Modules involved, as the `quickstart` archetype has not yet been updated for that.

Comment: In case you have a modular project, don't forget to add `requires org.assertj.core;` to your `module-info` file.

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks, but no Java Modules. The Maven `quickstart` archetype has not yet been updated for modules. I clarified in the Question. Just after posting, I found the solution: the `test` scope on the dependency restricts access to test classes only. Deleting that `test` scope opens AssertJ to use in your main app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## tl;dr

Change the `scope` element from `test` to `compile`. Or omit.

## Delete `<scope>test</scope>`

This topic was addressed in a [closed ticket # 520](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/520) on the AssertJ issue tracker.

When a Maven dependency carries a `scope` element with a value of `test`, that means you cannot use that library outside of your test-specific source package/folder.

If you are trying to call AssertJ from code in your example project’s `src/main/java/…` folder hierarchy, you will see that error. If you call AssertJ from `src/test/java…`, you will see success.

To enable AssertJ in the `src/main/java/…` folder hierarchy, delete the `scope` element in your POM dependency. So this:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

…becomes this:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Use default

Or change the `scope` element to the default value of `compile`.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

See the [*Dependency Scope*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) section of the Maven documentation.

---

FYI, the current version of *assertj-core* is `3.24.2` as of 2023-05.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is another crazy-a$$ situation, where changing version of imported library in pom.xml to outdated helped somehow... (removing `<scope>test</scope>` didn't help)

It's all fine when added dependency of this version of library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

[what import looks like (lovely) with 3.18.1 version imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jH9u.png)

But for some reason it just couldn't see assertj with this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.24.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[what import looks like (bad :c) with newest version imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5iw2.png)